# (edited) How to read this equation of sigma field?

Tags: probability-theory

[the equation is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPt5M.png)

i was shocked that there are intersection sign outside the bracket, which already weird enough to understand

the definition of sigma field is as below if you need
[omega-field definition is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZDgC.png)

Comment: Just for reference, $\sigma$ is called sigma.

Comment: thank you, i will edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{\mathcal{E} : \mathcal{D} \subseteq \mathcal{E} \text{ and } \mathcal{E} \text{ is a $\sigma$-field}\}$ is a set of sets (sometimes called a collection of sets). And the intersection means you intersect all of those sets.

For example

$$ \bigcap\big\{\{1,2,3\},\{2,3,5\},\{1,3,5\},\{3,5\}\big\} = \{1,2,3\} \cap \{2,3,5\} \cap\{1,3,5\} \cap \{3,5\} = \{3\}. $$

Comment: thanks, really helpful

Comment: Of course the given set is a collection $\sigma$-fields, while $\big\{\{1,2,3\},\{2,3,5\},\{1,3,5\},\{3,5\}\big\}$ is not. But a better example would be complicated, and the example _does_ illustrate what $\bigcap S$ means...